# Bug? when defining id, it says out of bounds when it shouldn't

Tags: officer

> layout_properties ( x = my_pres, layout = "Comparison", master = "Office Theme" )
>       master_name       name   type id                   ph_label                                                            ph      offx      offy
>   3  Office Theme Comparison   body 13        Text Placeholder 12  5.0625000 4.8298611
>   9  Office Theme Comparison   body  4      Content Placeholder 3                                      0.3927734 1.7009799
>   11 Office Theme Comparison   body 11        Text Placeholder 10  0.3923611 4.8290453
>   12 Office Theme Comparison   body  6      Content Placeholder 5                                   5.0625000 1.7009799
>   15 Office Theme Comparison   body  5         Text Placeholder 4                       5.0625011 1.2482754
>   16 Office Theme Comparison   body  3         Text Placeholder 2                                    0.3927734 1.2583486
>   20 Office Theme Comparison     dt  7         Date Placeholder 6                           0.3927734 5.2135422
>   25 Office Theme Comparison    ftr  8       Footer Placeholder 7                       3.3125000 5.2135422
>   30 Office Theme Comparison sldNum  9 Slide Number Placeholder 8                    7.3553718 5.2135422
>   34 Office Theme Comparison  title  2                    Title 1                                           0.392773

Couldn't find a nice way of formatting thsi but as you can see the type body has id of 13.

Now when I try to code this in:

```
GSK_Comparison <- function(PP,title,sub1,sub2,footer, table1,table2){
  PP <- PP %>% 
    add_slide(layout = "Comparison", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "title", str = title) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "body",index = 11, str = sub1) %>%
    ph_with_flextable(value = table1,type= "body",index = 4) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "body",index = 13, str = sub2) %>%
    ph_with_flextable(value = table2, type = "body", index = 6) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "dt", str = format(Sys.Date())) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "ftr",str = footer)
}
```

I get the following error message:
 Error in slide$get_location(type = type, index = index) : 
  body can only have 6 element(s) but index is set to 11

But not sure why this is occuring as clearly there are ID's of 11 and 13 for the type of body

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `index` is placeholder index (integer). This is to be used when a placeholder type is not unique in the current slide, e.g. two placeholders with type 'body', the first one will be added with index 1 and the second one with index 2.

Comment: Thanks - I have now looked at it and got it working but wondered how you defined indexes. will these always be in the order of index so index of 11 would be 5 and 13 would always be 6? I just tried all options to find out where they should be, but wondered if there was a set way - thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know why you are using 5, or 13, etc. It always starts with 1 in a slide, if you have two body placeholders, their index will be 1 and 2.